# Restrict Login for All pages for not logged in User: Symfony3

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

I am using `fos bundle` for Symfony and it's working fine but now I want to restrict `all pages` for `not logged user` except (login and register). How can I achieve that?

Comment: The first step is [reading the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html), the second step is trying. We are only the third step :/

Comment: Yes I read the doc and also tried but better solution will help someone also

Comment: there is no "Better" solution, the docu. is your best friend.

Answer (score 3):

security.yml need to look like this:

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/(register|login)?$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/?$, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

Check Documentation for more [Security Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) !

Greetings Violence

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you use [FosUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and as stated in the comments, it's all explained in the [Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html).

Have a look at "Step 4: Configure your application's security.yml"